# select all from XML in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xpath, sqlxml

How do I select all nodes from an XML in sql?

XML:

```
<value>
    <TradeId>5555</TradeId>
    <Account>SomeAccount</Account>
    <Book>1</Book>
    <LocalCcy>XXXX</LocalCcy>
    <ValuationCcy>XXXX</ValuationCcy>
    <PVLocal>44444444</PVLocal>
    <PresentValue>44444444</PresentValue>
    <InstrumentCode>XXXXXXXXX</InstrumentCode>
</value>
```

My SQL (that doesnt work):

```
SELECT   tradeRef.value('.','varchar(50)') AS strValue
    FROM @xmlData.nodes('data/value') AS trades(tradeRef)
    CROSS APPLY tradeRef.nodes('.') AS legColumns(nameRef)
```

This gives me all values but in one row...I would like one row per value..

Can you help me?

EDIT:

Requested output (just two first nodes here...):
[image]

Comment: Can you please specify how exactly you want your result table to look alike?

Comment: Sorry. Please see edit @GeorgScholz

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this approach:

```
declare @xmlData xml
select @xmlData = '<data><value>
    <TradeId>5555</TradeId>
    <Account>SomeAccount</Account>
    <Book>1</Book>
    <LocalCcy>XXXX</LocalCcy>
    <ValuationCcy>XXXX</ValuationCcy>
    <PVLocal>44444444</PVLocal>
    <PresentValue>44444444</PresentValue>
    <InstrumentCode>XXXXXXXXX</InstrumentCode>
</value></data>'

select
    t.c.value('./text()[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') as strValue
from  @xmlData.nodes('//value/child::node()') as t(c)
```

Comment: Is it possibly to make the TradeId appear on every row as well? As I wrote in edit? Maybe some CROSS APPLY, not sure..

Answer (score 2):

Possible way to get that output using `CROSS APPLY` :

```
declare @xmlData XML

set @xmlData = '<value>
    <TradeId>5555</TradeId>
    <Account>SomeAccount</Account>
    <Book>1</Book>
    <LocalCcy>XXXX</LocalCcy>
    <ValuationCcy>XXXX</ValuationCcy>
    <PVLocal>44444444</PVLocal>
    <PresentValue>44444444</PresentValue>
    <InstrumentCode>XXXXXXXXX</InstrumentCode>
</value>'

select
    P.X.value('.', 'int') as TradeId
    ,T.X.value('local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(100)') as NodeName
    ,T.X.value('.', 'nvarchar(100)') as NodeValue
from  @xmlData.nodes('//value/*[not(local-name()="TradeId")]') as T(X)
      cross apply T.X.nodes('../TradeId') as P(X)
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb/4811)**

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see `TradeId` as a column and don't want to see it as a row:

```
select
    t.c.value('(TradeId/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') as TradeId,
    r.c.value('local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(128)') as nodeName,
    r.c.value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') as strValue
from  @data.nodes('data/value') as t(c)
    cross apply t.c.nodes('*[local-name(.) != "TradeId"]') as r(c)
```

Or you can use parent axis `..` (although it usually performs worse):

```
select
    t.c.value('(../TradeId/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(128)') as TradeId,
    t.c.value('local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(128)') as nodeName,
    t.c.value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(128)') as nodeValue
from  @data.nodes('data/value/*[local-name(.) != "TradeId"]') as t(c)
```